# Wordpress site doens't load without index.php after migration from cpanel to plesk

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have migrated wordpress site from Linux hosting to Windows hosting (cpanel to plesk). Below are the details :

Linux : http://projects.iqlas.com/ongoing-projects/2015/gogreen/03062015/
Windows : http://mangium.com/projects/ggiqatar/29082015/

However, in the windows, the site doesn't work without index.php

Tried different steps with .htaccess but of no use.

This is .htaccess file.

```
#Begin Wordpress 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm 
RewriteBase /projects/ggiqatar/29082015/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /projects/ggiqatar/29082015/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projects/ggiqatar/29082015/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /projects/ggiqatar/29082015/index.php [L]
</IfModule>   
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone suggest as to what has to be done. Thanks.

Comment: Your Windows machine doesn't use Apache, but rather IIS. Therefore your .htaccess is indeed of no use. You should check your IIS setup for the required modifications.

Comment: so, is there some way i can get this site working without htaccess? it's wp migration.

Comment: It depends on your access level to the server. Basically you can look [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-indexphp-in-permalinks-using-iis-8) for some ideas. Google for IIS Wordpress instructions.